# Which characters must be escaped in a Perl regex pattern

Tags: regex, perl

Im trying to find files that are looking like this:

```
access_log-20160101
access_log-20160304
...
```

with perl regex i came up with something like this:

```
/^access_log-\d{8}$/
```

But im not sure about the "_" and the "-". are these metacharacter?
What is the expression for this?

i read that "_" in regex is something like \w, but how do i use them in my exypression?

```
/^access\wlog-\d{8}$/ ?
```

Comment: use quotemeta to escape metacharacters. If you want to check try `perl -e 'print quotemeta("access_log-")'`

Comment: Underscore `_` is in SQL `LIKE` patterns though, which aren't full regexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underscore (`_`) is not a metacharacter and does not need to be quoted (though it won't change anything if you quote it).

Hyphen (`-`) IS a metacharacter that defines the range between two symbols inside a bracketed character class. However, **in this particular position,** it will be interpreted verbatim and doesn't need quoting since it is not inside `[]` with a symbol on both sides.

You can use your regexp as is; hyphens (`-`) might need quoting if your format changes in future.

Comment: `-` is only a Metacharacter inside character classes, so need to worry for the OP at all in this case, e.g. `a-z` matches `a-z` literally whereas `[a-z]` matches a single lowercase letter

Comment: @SebastianProske, thanks, updated. That's what I get for using too many different pattern specifications from different engines.

Comment: @Borodin, "Quoted" is used interchangably with "escaped". For example look up `perlre`, especially `\Q` part.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: IMO it is horrible to use *quoting* when you mean *escaping*. How would you describe making `[` into `"["`? And since there is a common unambiguous verb that says what you mean, why not use it? I shall raise a bug report about `perlre`

Comment: @Borodin, you'd need to bug report `quotemeta` first - it is right in the name. This is not a bug or "another meaning", just two English words used interchangeably in this context. For example en.wiki article on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character uses it too.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: Yes, I've mentioned `quotemeta` and `\Q` in my bug report. Of course I'm aware that *quote* is often used to mean *escape*, but in the context of programming where the former can mean several critically different things it is just lazy not to say *escape* when that is what you mean

Comment: @ThisSuitsIsBlackNot, guys, why are you so hellbent on acting Captain Obvious and stating that `_` is underscore and `-` is hypen as if somebody would think that they are a tree and bicycle instead? First Borodin, now you, I don't get it.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex pattern is exactly right

Neither underscore `_` nor hyphen `-` need to be escaped. Outside a square-bracketed character class, the twelve Perl regex metacharacters are

- Brackets `(` `)` `[` `{`
- Quantifiers `*` `+` `?`
- Anchors `^` `$`
- Alternator `|`
- Wild character `.`
- The escape itself `\`

and only these must be escaped

If the pattern of your file names doesn't vary from what you have shown then the pattern that you are using

```
^access_log-\d{8}$
```

is correct, unless you need to validate the date string

---

***Within a character class*** like `[A-F]` you *must* escape the hyphen if you want it to be interpreted literally. As it stands, that class is the equivalent to `[ABCDEF]`. If you mean just the three characters `A`, `-` or `F` then `[A\-F]` will do what you want, but it is usual to put the hyphen at the start or end of the class list to make it unambiguous. `[-AF]` and `[AF-]` are the same as `[A\-F]` and rather more readable

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to add a link to [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions), which describes the metacharacters in a concise little table.

Comment: @MattJacob: I think you've done that for me! Thanks Matt

Comment: See the [perlrecharclass man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Special-Characters-Inside-a-Bracketed-Character-Class) for other characters that must be escaped in character classes.